# Install PHP 5.5 on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to use the AWS PHP SDK on Amazon Linux 2.  I thought this should be easy.

I've enabled the `epel` repo which has `php-aws-sdk` version 2.8.31.  But the [developer guide](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/php/) recommends version 3.  SDK version 3 depends on PHP 5.5 but this distro comes with 5.4.

I don't see php 5.5 in the default repos.
`amazon-linux-extras` provides php 7.1, 7.2, and 7.3.
Why is it so hard to get 5.5 which is required for this SDK?

Comment: "To use the AWS SDK for PHP, you must be using PHP version 5.5.0 or later" – is 7.x not possible?

Comment: Doh!  I didn't notice that part.  Yes my app is compatible with 7.1 so that should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install PHP 5.5, as `php-aws-sdk` is [compatible with PHP 5.5 *and above*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_requirements.html), so the version of PHP 7 in the repositories (`amazon-linux-extras`) will work.